# Eclipse Android runtime exception Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am unable to get this application to launch. It is a tutorial from my book. As far as I know it has to do with the `ActionBarActivity`. If any other information is needed I will to provide it.

```
02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{net.jthomas.concerttickets/net.jthomas.concerttickets.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at net.jthomas.concerttickets.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)

02-08 01:53:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  ... 11 more
```

This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JvNS.png) of my project.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 3):

If it is the ActionBarActivity thats the problem and you dont intend to use the actionbar you can replace `extends ActionBarActivity` with `extends Activity`

If you want the action bar then add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to your activity tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: The only issue with that is the teacher is going to count off if the code does not match the book. When I replace the theme everything works fine other than the look of the app. Is there any way to install an older version of the Android SDK manager or the tools it uses that cause this error?

Comment: What theme does the book say to use?

Comment: What you can do is use the android sdk manager to download the api that the book is for. Once you've done that you can create a new project and set the target api to the one in the book. The books code should work fine then.